# How can I scroll to a specified line in a WinForms TextBox using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, line

How can I scroll to a specified line in a WinForms TextBox using C#?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of textbox (ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF?) and what exactly do you mean by "go to"? Select the whole line? Force it to scroll the line into view?

Comment: WinForms... move the mouse to the specified line

Comment: how ican loop trought the TextBox? i am an beginner in programming

Answer (score 29):

Here's how you scroll to the selection:

```
textBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

To scroll to a specified line, you could loop through the TextBox.Lines property, total their lengths to find the start of the specified line and then set TextBox.SelectionStart to position the caret.

Something along the lines of this (untested code):

```
int position = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < lineToGoto; i++)
{
    position += textBox.Lines[i].Length;
}

textBox.SelectionStart = position;

textBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: Alternatively, "position = textBox.Text.Length" to avoid the loop.

Comment: Instead of looping, you can use GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(). There is an issue related to displayed vs assigned lines, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getfirstcharindexfromline.aspx

Answer (score 10):

```
    private void MoveCaretToLine(TextBox txtBox, int lineNumber)
    {
        txtBox.HideSelection = false;
        txtBox.SelectionStart = txtBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNumber - 1);
        txtBox.SelectionLength = txtBox.Lines[lineNumber - 1].Length;
        txtBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the best solution I found:

```
const int EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE = 0x00CE;
const int EM_LINESCROLL = 0x00B6;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

void SetLineIndex(TextBox tbx, int lineIndex)
{
  int currentLine = SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE, 0, 0);
  SendMessage(tbx.Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, lineIndex - currentLine);
}
```

It has the benefit, that the selection and caret position is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

The looping answer to find the proper caret position has a couple of problems.  First, for large text boxes, it's slow.  Second, tab characters seem to confuse it.  A more direct route is to use the text on the line that you want.

```
String textIWantShown = "Something on this line.";
int position = textBox.Text.IndexOf(textIWantShown);
textBox.SelectionStart = position;
textBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

This text must be unique, of course, but you can obtain it from the textBox.Lines array.  In my case, I had prepended line numbers to the text I was displaying, so this made life easier.

Comment: Looping indeed has problems, it did not work for me. It seemed as if the count was off by 1 for each line. In any case, one can use GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(), which worked for me.

Comment: -1: By the way, I believe your method is wrong. What if the user wants to scroll to line 1000, which happens to be empty? Your code will go to the first occurrence of "1000", which need not be on line 1000.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from user 1027167:

```
void SetLineIndex(TextBox tbx, int lineIndex)
{
  int currentLine = SendMessage(textBox1.Handle
```

helpful in solving my problem (I have a text box which demonstrates what selected text looks like and I wanted the insertion cursor at 0 while maintaining the selection). However, it looks like there is a typo:

```
void SetLineIndex(TextBox pTheTextBox, int lineIndex)
{
  int currentLine = SendMessage(pTheTextBox.Handle
```

In the simplest of test cases, with a single TextBox, these two variables will often resolve to the same TextBox.