# Scroll to bottom of C# TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a TextBox on a C# Forms Application. I populate the TextBox with information on the Load event of the form. I then call the following:

```
this.txtLogEntries.SelectionStart = txtLogEntries.Text.Length;
this.txtLogEntries.ScrollToCaret();
```

However the TextBox does not scroll to the bottom ?

This only applies to the Load event though. I also update this TextBox from other parts of the application once it's running, and as soon as one of these events update's the TextBox, it is scrolled to the bottom.

So, how can I get it to scroll to the bottom when pre populating the TextBox in the Form Load event?

Comment: Check
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739656/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specified-line-in-a-winforms-textbox-using-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739656/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specified-line-in-a-winforms-textbox-using-c)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try putting the code in the Form's Shown event:

```
private void myForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtLogEntries.SelectionStart = txtLogEntries.Text.Length;
  txtLogEntries.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

While the [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event (occurs *before* the Form is shown) is processed, there is no form to display yet, and thus no visual state has been established. Scrolling a non-visible control therefore very likely doesn't do anything because—hey, there is nothing to scroll as a scrolling viewport is just a view on the control but not part of its state.

You may have more success with moving the scrolling part into the [`Shown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) event (occurs *after* the form is first shown) of the form