# Scroll to the end of a Single-Line Textbox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In regards to single-line textboxes (Multiline property is set to false), is it possible to scroll to the end of the line when the text length exceeds the horizontal size of the box?

I have tried various solutions that work for multi-line boxes, but none of them have worked thus far.

Very similar questions have been asked by several individuals in the past, but it has always regarded Multi-Line textboxes. The questions/solutions that I have come across on SO are the following:

[Scroll to bottom of C# TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1228675/1415616)

[How do I automatically scroll to the bottom of a multiline text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/898307/1415616)

Right now I have the following code (which seemingly does not work):

```
PathText.Text = "";
PathText.AppendText(BrowseDialog.SelectedPath);
PathText.SelectionStart = PathText.TextLength;
PathText.ScrollToCaret();
PathText.Refresh();
```

`PathText` is the textbox in use, and `BrowseDialog` is a FileDialog.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess: PathText.SelectionStart = PathText.Text.Length;

Comment: You are correct; I initially copied old code that I had not compiled yet when I typed up the question. Thanks for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
 PathText.Focus();
 PathText.Select(PathText.Text.Length, 0);
```

Comment: The problem was elsewhere in the code apparently, but I will go ahead and mark this as the answer because .Focus(); is a crucial part of the process based on the previous questions and other discussions I found from the Google searches.
Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

```
textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
// call focus 
textBox1.Focus();
```

OR

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
textBox1.Focus();
```