# Textbox scrollbar always stay at the bottom?

Tags: c#, textbox

Is there a way i can make sure my textbox scroll bar always stays at the bottom because my textbox is my messages. It looks alot better if it is at the bottom

At the start it changes my text to the text from a database so i just did this void

```
private void frmMain_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
    textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

but it didnt work. Is there any other ways? I also tryed putting them 2 codes in Form1_Load

Comment: Where is it currently if not on the bottom?  Do you have a screenshot of it being in another place?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is in the wrong event. You are trying to scroll to the bottom when `frmMain` has it's `Text` change. You want to run your code when the `textBox1` has its text change, not the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add your code for the `Shown` event for your Form so you 'would end up with code like this:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
        textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

Kindly check that [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228675/scroll-to-bottom-of-c-sharp-textbox) for this solution and another ways