# autoscroll a textbox in c# 1 line down every x seconds

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, scroll, autoscroll

im trying to get a textbox to autoscroll a line down every X seconds.
i have found the AutoScrollOffset and ScrollToCaret functions, but these functions do not give the desired result.

I think my solution would be to do the autoscroll function in a backgroundworkerthread, that does a scroll down by 1 line every x seconds. But i have no idea how to, and info from the net isnt verry usefull either.

I hope someone can help me, thnx in advance!

(im using .net 4.5)

Comment: @GrantWinney not 100% correct there. You CAN modify the GUI from a background thread BUT the thread needs a handle on the GUI (for example the mainform) and then you need to use invoke there (been there, did that, and hated the problems this can cause as you need to see if a handle exists and put a try/catch block around it and still pray that there is no racing condition
).

Comment: somewhat related there (for the scroll itself): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739656/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specified-line-in-a-winforms-textbox-using-c

Comment: @GrantWinney here are the main functions i use http://pastebin.com/XPRkis4i (nothing concidering the scrolling is done yet)  many thanks for your guys replys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13106107), and combining it with a `Timer`, you could do something like this:

```
private int lineNumber = 1;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nfobox.HideSelection = false;
    nfobox.SelectionStart = nfobox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNumber - 1);
    nfobox.SelectionLength = nfobox.Lines[lineNumber - 1].Length;
    nfobox.ScrollToCaret();

    lineNumber++;

    // include some code to detect the last line, or you'll get an exception
}
```

This will only work if your lines are separated by a line feed.

If it's one long line that wraps, then the whole thing will be selected on the first "tick" and then it's done.

Comment: sorry i just saw the "GetFirstCharIndexFromLine" and deleted the comment ;)

Comment: @GrantWinney I thank you verry verry much! this got it working!

Comment: @GrantWinney nope, that public void setTxt method works fine, im not trying to give a textbox to that method, since the textbox i use (nfobox) is already defined for the whole class, and i can set the Text property fine this way :)

Answer (score 0):

"Grant Winney" is rigth. you can't directly modify the Uİ from a background thread.
But You use the way below.

```
int lineCounter = 0;
    int nextLineLength = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.SelectionStart = nextLineLength;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
        textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        nextLineLength += textBox1.Lines[lineCounter++].Length + "\r\n".Length; //"\r\n" is next line parameters

    }
```